# Can not create SSH tunnel with PHP function ssh2_tunnel

Tags: php, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm using PHP 5.6 with ssh2 extension to create SSH tunnel to a remote host, here is my code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host[0], 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $host[1], $host[2])) {
if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 1080)){
 //curl commands
 }
}
```

I can do some Linux commands working with `ssh2_exec` but can not create SSH tunnel with `ssh2_tunnel`, here the error logs:

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_tunnel(): Unable to request a channel from remote host

Anybody can give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

The SSH server that you're connecting to does not have TCP forwarding enabled (i.e, `AllowTcpForwarding no`). You will need to ask the server administrator to enable it.

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff, i have tested on my own server and `AllowTcpForwarding yes` was set by default. I have tunneled successfully using Putty through this server but cant find a way to do with PHP